# Textfield default value to user email NOT WEBFORM

Tags: forms

I am using the Drupal 6 Form API to build a custom form. I am not using the Webform module or CCK. How do I assign the user's email as a default value for a form element?

I know about `#default_value =>` but I do not know what to assign to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your form function, you can add `global $user;` at the top. Then in your #default_value you can use `$user->mail`.